# How to add custom plugin in CKEditor 5 on Laravel Vue 2

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, ckeditor, ckeditor5

How to add a custom plugin, more specifically the Inline widget plugin as mentioned in the example of the [documentation of CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/tutorials/implementing-an-inline-widget.html#full-source-code) in `vue CKEditor` ?

I have tried to follow the CKEditor setup process using [CKEditor from source](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/vuejs-v2.html#using-ckeditor-from-source).
Since Laravel Vue doesn't have `vue.config.js` i have copied the same code on `webpack.mix.js`. Initially it failed to complied with an error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/theme/mixins/_rwd.css' in '
```

But after removing some of the plugins such as `LinkPlugin, it complies but it run into another error

```
app.js?id=00c39e33120645d3026e:82180 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')
    at IconView._updateXMLContent (app.js?id=00c39e33120645d3026e:63098)
    at IconView.render (app.js?id=00c39e33120645d3026e:63074)
    at IconView.<anonymous> (app.js?id=00c39e33120645d3026e:80777)
    at IconView.fire (app.js?id=00c39e33120645d3026e:78186)
    at IconView.<computed> [as render] (app.js?id=00c39e33120645d3026e:80781)
    at ViewCollection._renderViewIntoCollectionParent (app.js?id=00c39e33120645d3026e:72022)
    at ViewCollection.<anonymous> (app.js?id=00c39e33120645d3026e:71883)
    at ViewCollection.fire (app.js?id=00c39e33120645d3026e:78186)
    at ViewCollection.addMany (app.js?id=00c39e33120645d3026e:74031)
    at ViewCollection.add (app.js?id=00c39e33120645d3026e:73996)
```

Same issue as mentioned here
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue/issues/24#issuecomment-947333698
But this solution didn't work for me.

Here is my complete **webpack.mix.js** file

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .version();

const path = require('path');
const CKEditorWebpackPlugin = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin');
const {styles} = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils');

module.exports = {
    // The source of CKEditor is encapsulated in ES6 modules. By default, the code
    // from the node_modules directory is not transpiled, so you must explicitly tell
    // the CLI tools to transpile JavaScript files in all ckeditor5-* modules.
    transpileDependencies: [
        /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]src[/\\].+\.js$/,
    ],

    configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            // CKEditor needs its own plugin to be built using webpack.
            new CKEditorWebpackPlugin({
                // See https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/ui-language.html
                language: 'en',

                // Append translations to the file matching the `app` name.
                translationsOutputFile: /app/
            })
        ]
    },

    // Vue CLI would normally use its own loader to load .svg and .css files, however:
    //  1. The icons used by CKEditor must be loaded using raw-loader,
    //  2. The CSS used by CKEditor must be transpiled using PostCSS to load properly.
    chainWebpack: config => {
        // (1.) To handle editor icons, get the default rule for *.svg files first:
        const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg');

        // More rule
        const filesRuleIndex = config.module.rules.findIndex(item => {
            return item.test.test('.svg')
        })

        if (filesRuleIndex !== -1) {
            config.module.rules[filesRuleIndex].test = /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)$/
            const svgRule = {...config.module.rules[filesRuleIndex]}
            svgRule.test = /\.svg/
            svgRule.exclude = svgRule.exclude || []
            svgRule.exclude.push(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '@ckeditor'))
            config.module.rules.push(svgRule)
        }

        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
            use: ["raw-loader"]
        })

        // Then you can either:
        //
        // * clear all loaders for existing 'svg' rule:
        //
        //  svgRule.uses.clear();
        //
        // * or exclude ckeditor directory from node_modules:
        svgRule.exclude.add(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '@ckeditor'));

        // Add an entry for *.svg files belonging to CKEditor. You can either:
        //
        // * modify the existing 'svg' rule:
        //
        //      svgRule.use( 'raw-loader' ).loader( 'raw-loader' );
        //
        // * or add a new one:
        config.module
            .rule('cke-svg')
            .test(/ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/)
            .use('raw-loader')
            .loader('raw-loader');

        // (2.) Transpile the .css files imported by the editor using PostCSS.
        // Make sure only the CSS belonging to ckeditor5-* packages is processed this way.
        config.module
            .rule('cke-css')
            .test(/ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\].+\.css$/)
            .use('postcss-loader')
            .loader('postcss-loader')
            .tap(() => {
                return styles.getPostCssConfig({
                    themeImporter: {
                        themePath: require.resolve('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark'),
                    },
                    minify: true
                });
            });


    },


};
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the proper way of setting this CKEditor to work with custom plugins

**And my vue component script is like this**

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue2';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
import EssentialsPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import BoldPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import ItalicPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';
//import LinkPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link';
import ParagraphPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';

//Custom Plugin same as in the documentation mentioned above, 
//import Placeholder from "../../editor-plugins/Placeholder"; // Commented out
export default {
    name: "AddEditDocuments",
    props: {},
    components:{
        ckeditor: CKEditor.component
    },
    data() {
        return {
            editor: ClassicEditor,
            editorData: '',
            editorConfig: {
                plugins: [
                    EssentialsPlugin,
                    BoldPlugin,
                    ItalicPlugin,
                    // LinkPlugin,
                    ParagraphPlugin
                ],

                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'bold',
                        'italic',
                        'link',
                        'undo',
                        'redo'
                    ]
                }
            },\
          

}
```

**Packages:**

- Laravel : 8.76.1
- Vue 2
- CKEditor 5

Answer (score 0):

Dont use CKEditor5 as it has some bugs in its editor just because of this i was also switch to CKEditor 4. After installing CKeditor using npm use it in the component. No need to configure it globally.

```html
<template>
    <ckeditor v-model="obj[name]" :config="editorConfig" ></ckeditor>
</template>

<script>
import CKEditor from 'ckeditor4-vue';

export default {
    name: "Ckeditor",
    props: {
        obj: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
    },
    components: {
        ckeditor: CKEditor.component
    },
    data(){
        return {
            editorConfig: {
                toolbar: [
                    [
                    'Bold',
                    'Italic',
                    'Link',
                    'BulletedList',
                    'NumberedList',
                    'Undo',
                    'Redo',
                ]
                ],
                removePlugins: 'elementspath',
                extraPlugins: 'filebrowser,uploadimage',
                height: 100,
                resize_enabled:false,
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: I thought of the same, but I want those custom plugins such as placeholder and then block widgets.
Not sure how to do in the CKEditor 4 that is why sticking with this

Comment: You can review that documentation https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_plugins.html. Moreover I m  adding the plugin importing code above